# How to use like clause over string separated with comma inside case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @IsSearch_  BIT;
SET @IsSearch_ ='True'
DECLARE @Organization_  VARCHAR(100);
SET @Organization_ ='111,111A'

select *
from VYC20 C20
where (@Organization_ IS NULL) 
  OR (1 = CASE @IsSearch_
          WHEN 0 THEN (CASE WHEN @Organization_ IS NOT NULL
                            AND C20.ORG IN 
                                (select value
                                from STRING_SPLIT(@Organization_, ','))
                            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          WHEN 1 THEN (CASE WHEN C20.ORG like @Organization_ + '%'
                             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          ELSE 0 END)
```

In the above query the 1st case WHEN 0 statement with IN clause gives the correct record, but the  WHEN 1 THEN gives me 0 records, can someone please help me how to apply like clause with string separated with comma.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Just Try posting some sample data with Example and Expected output

Comment: I'm able to get the records by using the below query: 
`select * from VYC20  C20 INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@Organization_, ',') s ON C20.ORG  LIKE  s.value + '%'`
But i'm trying hard to do same in case statement.

Comment: `@Organization_ + '%'` means it must start with that value

Comment: @jarlh yes, the actual stored proc is quite big and in the where clause i'm using and/or in or there is this case statement.

Comment: @Charlieface I want to use like clause with comma separated string values as in `@Organization_` inside case.

Comment: If they are comma-separated then why use `LIKE`? Or do you mean to say that you want to use `LIKE` *after* splitting the values?

Comment: @Charlieface  yes i want to get all the records that starts with that value after splitting each value. I want split each string and then get all the records that starts with that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you actually want is to use `LIKE` *after* splitting

```sql
DECLARE @IsSearch_  BIT = 1;
DECLARE @Organization_ VARCHAR(100) = '111,111A';

SELECT *
FROM VYC20 C20
WHERE @Organization_ IS NULL
   OR (@IsSearch_ = 0 AND
      C20.ORG IN 
          (SELECT s.value
          FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Organization_, ',') s))
   OR (@IsSearch_ = 1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Organization_, ',') s
          WHERE C20.ORG LIKE s.value + '%'));
```

---

I *strongly* advise you to do this in a set-based fashion and use a table variable or Table Parameter

```sql
DECLARE @IsSearch_  BIT = 1;
DECLARE @Organization_ TABLE (value VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @Organization_ VALUES('111'),('111A');

SELECT *
FROM VYC20 C20
WHERE @IsSearch_ = -1  -- include all
   OR (@IsSearch_ = 0 AND
      C20.ORG IN 
          (SELECT s.value
          FROM @Organization_ s))
   OR (@IsSearch_ = 1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM @Organization_ s
          WHERE C20.ORG LIKE s.value + '%'));
```

Comment: In my Query I've replace the `WHEN 1 THEN (CASE WHEN C20.ORG like @Organization_ + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`  with `WHEN 1 THEN (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Organization_, ',') s WHERE C20.ORG LIKE s.value + '%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. It seems to me it is giving correct result. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but why use `CASE` at all? Just use normal `AND/OR` logic